# Google Maps API V2 - InfoWindow miss the marker

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I believe the picture says everything. I have my app running on several devices, but ONLY with this particular device of friend of mine (a Galaxy S4) the **InfoWindow** miss the marker.

My guess it is something related to the very high density of his device (XXHIGH).

[image]

I also installed the sample map application from the SKD on his device and the result is the same, which proves that there's nothing wrong with my code:

[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest posting this on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2) with a screenshot from maps sample app.

**Edit:**

Posted here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5439

Comment: @Exception-al Good to hear that. Wanted to edit answer with the update.